# get states of country return null

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, pdo

I am trying to get country states but it returns null
here is my code
the adding form

```
<select class="form-control" id="country-dropdown">
    <option value="">Select Country</option>
    <?php 
    $countries = get_rows('tbl_countries');
    foreach($countries as $country):
        echo '<option value='.$country['id'].'>'.$country['name'].'</option>';
    endforeach;
    ?>
</select>

<select name="state" class="form-control" id="state-dropdown" required="required">
</select>

<select name="city" class="form-control" id="city-dropdown" required="required">
</select>
```

Ajax Code
to get country states

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#country-dropdown').on('change', function() {
    var country_id = this.value;
    $.ajax({
        url: "getStates.php",
        type: "GET",
        data: {
            country_id: country_id
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function(result){
            $("#state-dropdown").html(result);
            $('#city-dropdown').html('<option value="">Select State First</option>'); 
            console.log("this is "+ result);
        }
    });
});    
$('#state-dropdown').on('change', function() {
        var state_id = this.value;
        $.ajax({
            url: "getCities.php",
            type: "GET",
            data: {
                state_id: state_id
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function(result){
                $("#city-dropdown").html(result);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

code in getStates file

```
<?php
//connect file
include "../init.php";
$country_id = $_GET['country_id'];
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_states WHERE country_id = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($country_id));
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach($rows as $row){
    echo '<option value='.$row['id'].'>'.$row['name'].'</option>';
}
```

The result is null
if I remove the country_id condition it returns all states not the choosen country states
wheres the problem with my code

Comment: Check the HTML of the country dropdown and make sure the IDs are correct.

Comment: nothing wrong in HTML code all IDS are correct

Comment: Then I can't see a reason why this isn't working. Check the Network tab to make sure the parameter is being sent. Add `var_dump($_POST);` to the PHP.

Comment: its return array contains country_id and country_id send successfully in network tab

Comment: Try using `$country_id = intval($_GET['country_id']);`. Maybe there's a problem comparing it to a string.

Comment: still returning null

Comment: If the country ID is correct and can be found in `tbl_states`, I can't think of any reason why you're getting an empty result.